# .htaccess redirect css file to php

Tags: php, css, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

I took my file.css file and rename it to file.php and add this code at the first line on the new php file :

```
<?php
    session_start();
    header("Content-type: text/css");
?>
/* css content goes here ... */
```

Now I am trying to redirect all request from http://puaction.com/css/file.css to http://puaction.com/css/file.php via htaccess BUT it's not working... :/

what's wrong with my htaccess file?

That's my .htaccess file :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule file.css file.php
```

Comment: Where is `.htaccess`?

Comment: I don't see an .htaccess file?

Comment: I have just add my htaccess file... take a look. Thanks !

Comment: Does your Apache configuration allow you to change these settings in a `.htaccess` file? If yes, then perhaps refer to Apache's documentation on the topic of `mod_rewrite`: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/remapping.html

Answer (score 0):

In the htaccess file in your document root, add:

```
Redirect 301 /css/file.css /css/file.php
```